# scanf with formatted float

Tags: c, input, scanf

The following codes seem to give inconsistent answers instead of expected result, I wonder why.

```
$ cat chk.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        float a;

        scanf("%4.1f", &a);
        printf("%4.1f\n", a);

        return 0;
}

$ cc chk.c && ./a.out
12.1
 0.0
$
```

This does not read properly the input at all! Can anyone explain this behavior please? I tried multiple GCC versions on Linux with the same result and net search was not useful either.

Comment: Precision in not part of the `scanf` format specification.

Comment: Step 1: drop the `'\n'` in `scanf("%4f\n", &a);`.  This takes care of the first problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have whitespace in the `scanf` format, it means to read all characters until there is no more whitespace.  In order to do this, it has to wait until you enter something that isn't whitespace, so it appears as if it is asking you to enter more than one value. Using `"\n"` doesn't mean read a single newline charater, it means read **all** whitespace.

Unlike the `printf` format string, precision is not part of the `scanf` format string, so `scanf` is simply failing to read the float in your second example.  You end up printing an uninitialized value, which happens to print `0.0`. Getting the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior, so it could have done anything.